# Left join in Bulk API

Tags: soql, query, bulk-api

I need to load all accounts along with their owners' names, was trying next query:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Owner), LastModifiedDate FROM Account
```

Got next error:

> InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: INVALID_TYPE:  (SELECT
>   FirstName, LastName FROM Owner), LastModifiedDate FROM Account
>   ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:54 Didn't understand relationship 'Owner' in
>   FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
>   relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names.

Did another try:

```
SELECT Id, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, LastModifiedDate FROM Account
```

Got another error:

> InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED:
>   Foreign Key Relationships not supported in Bulk Query

How can I get owners (first name + last name) of accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you create formulas to pull in this information.

**Owner_First_Name__c**

```
Owner.FirstName
```

**Owner_Last_Name__c**

```
Owner.LastName
```

Now the Bulk API will support your query:

```
SELECT Id, Owner_First_Name__c, Owner_Last_Name__c LastModifiedDate FROM Account
```